# Seeking OS X app recommendation: instant text entry

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, twitter

I'm looking for an app (or script) that does this:

1. I hit a global shortcut key chord.
2. A one-line text entry box appears.
3. I enter a line of text and hit ENTER.
4. The text is saved somewhere, perhaps as a plaintext file on the local filesystem.
5. I'm looking at the same screen I was before step 1, without any more clicks, keys, or delays.

That's it.  The purpose is simply to have a muscle-memory way of recording a very brief thought.  Please don't suggest a solution that involves a heavy app with lots of features -- for the sake of this OP, that fails the requirements.

This description sounds a lot like Twitter, and given that many OS X Twitter clients could be configured to fulfill this behavior, I don't want a Twitter client.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without any third party software. Just use *Automator* to create your own *Service* that appends the input string to any text file.

---

Open *Automator* and select to create a new *Service* that receives *no input* in *any application*.

From the *Library*, drag the *Run AppleScript* action to the area on the right, and use the following script code:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    return text returned of (display dialog "Enter some text:" default answer "")
end run
```

Then, add a *Run Shell Script* action that receives input *to stdin*, and replace the default script with the following:

```
cat >> /Users/danielbeck/notes.txt
```

Instead of `/Users/danielbeck/notes.txt`, specify any path.

Here's what it looks like in Automator:

> [image]

Save as e.g. *Add Note*, and assign a keyboard shortcut in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Services » General » Add Note*

Here's the dialog box:

[image]

You can press *Cancel*, `Escape`, or `Cmd-Period` to cancel.

---

You can even change how the notes appear in the text file through changes to the *Run Shell Script* action. For example, you can use the following instead, if you reconfigure the *Run Shell Script* action to receive input *as arguments* instead:

```
echo $( date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" ) "$@" >> /Users/danielbeck/notes.txt
```

It will look like this in the resulting file:

```
2012-01-30 12:38:56 foo
2012-01-30 12:38:58 bar
```

Comment: This solution requires that the frontmost application supports services. All well-behaved OS X applications do, but programs with horrible platform integration (usually cross-platform programs) like Firefox, Microsoft Word, or MacVim might not work.

Answer (score 1):

The QuickJot feature of [Shovebox](http://wonderwarp.com/shovebox/) does this. [Yojimbo](http://www.barebones.com/products/yojimbo/) also has a hot key feature, but the input box will be a little more complex. Both of these will store "files" within the application, not in the file system per say.

If you are dead set on storing plain text in the file system [Notational Velocity](http://notational.net/) or [nvAlt](http://brettterpstra.com/project/nvalt/) may better suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

notational velocity would be a very good choice & it's free.

simply set up a global hotkey & enter the text

you can also customize the size of the window

Answer (score 0):

I use totalterminal for this along with vim. I press ctrl twice and it drops me into vim, where I can add to an open notes file.  I pressume you could probably get away with just keeping textedit open on a notes.txt but I like the colours of terminal :)